# PHP date limit 1970

Tags: php, date

I'm programming a site about genealogy, I used the date input to acquire dates, and

```
$datamm= strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($_POST['datamm']));
```

to convert the dates for the database, but the minimum value that I can get is `1970-01-01`. I need to acquire dates between 1500 and current day.

What can I do to solve the problem?? I prefer procedural solution if it is possible.

Comment: Because that's the [UNIX Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Consider using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example,

```
<?php 
  $date = new DateTime( '01-01-1950' );
  echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d' );
?>
```

DateTime is great, you can do all sorts once you understand it.

For instance, this will add a year and echo the start and end dates,

```
<?php 
  $date = new DateTime( '01-01-1950' );
  echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d' )."\n";
  $date->modify( '+1 years' );
  echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that in which format your date is coming from input then you can try:

```
$datamm = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', $_POST['datamm']);//You know that date is coming in j-M-Y format
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // You can save in Y-m-d format in database
```

if you are taking timestamp as input then :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',$_POST['datamm']);//you are taking timestamp like : 30000000000 as an input
echo $date;//make in database in Y-m-d format
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please try to see if it fits your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
// pass your date format 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y','17 Jan 1500');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/673359)**

Answer (score 0):

You should probably focus on using some 3rd party library instead of official PHP's datetime functions.

For example, for your advanced date-time manipulating requirements, a good alternative for PHP's standard datetime would be moment.php

It's inspired by moment.js library whose goal is to fix common date-time programming issues, and bring standardization to higher level.

You can obtain it via composer like:

```
{
  "require": {
    "fightbulc/moment": "*"
  }
}
```

Or via github for manual installation.

To parse various input date consult a manual, below is example:

```
$m = new \Moment\Moment('1503-04-25T03:00:00', 'CET');
```

There is also other alternatives to explore, for example:
https://github.com/swt83/php-date